# Calculate subtotals in R dataframe for specific range of values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame `df` which has the following structure:

```
NEW_UPC         IRI_KEY     WEEK      DOLLARS
13000016961     272568      1220      3.29
13000016961     272568      1221      3.29
13000016961     272568      1222      3.29
13000016961     272568      1223      9.87
13000016962     272568      1224      3.29
13000016961     272568      1224      9.87
13000016962     272568      1225      3.29
13000016961     272568      1225      9.87
13000016962     272568      1226      3.29
13000016961     272568      1226      9.87
13000016961     272568      1227      9.87
13000016961     272568      1228      3.29
13000016963     272568      1228      3.29
13000016963     272568      1229      3.29
13000016962     272568      1230      3.29
13000016961     272568      1230      3.29
13000016963     272568      1230      13.16
13000016962     272568      1231      3.29
13000016963     272568      1231      9.87
21600016430     272568      1231      17.43
13000016962     272568      1232      9.87
```

I am trying to obtain the sum of `DOLLARS` for the first 12 weeks for each `NEW_UPC`-`IRI_KEY` combination. I tried the following code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(NEW_UPC,IRI_KEY) %>% 
  mutate(START = min(WEEK), END = max(WEEK)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(NEW_UPC,IRI_KEY) %>%
  summarise(Sales = case_when(WEEK<=(START+12) ~ sum(DOLLARS)))
```

But, I got the following error message:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `Sales` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 8
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDITED: The values in column `Sales` changed to real totals to avoid confusion raised in a comment.

The final output that I would like to get is as follows:

```
NEW_UPC         IRI_KEY     Sales
13000016961     272568      65.8
13000016962     272568      26.3
13000016963     272568      29.6
21600016430     272568      17.4
```

Please note that the values in the `Sales` column above are just random numbers that I put to show the structure of the output. Also, if a `NEW_UPC` has values of `DOLLARS` beyond 12 weeks from `START`, I would like to get the total for the first 12 weeks only. So, the `Sales` column should return the total upto first 12 weeks from `START`. Alternately, if a `NEW_UPC` has values of `DOLLARS` for less than 12 weeks from `START`, then `Sales` should return the total for that period.

Comment: I am confused as to how you get the numbers for the output, as the sum of dollars in your dataframe is 139.16...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost near to solution. You can sort data on `WEEK` and then take top (`head`) 12 will provide you data for first 12 weeks. You can try as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(NEW_UPC,IRI_KEY) %>%
  arrange(WEEK) %>%
  summarise(Sales = sum(head(DOLLARS,12)))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups: NEW_UPC [?]
#       NEW_UPC IRI_KEY Sales
#         <dbl>   <int> <dbl>
# 1 13000016961  272568  65.8
# 2 13000016962  272568  26.3
# 3 13000016963  272568  29.6
# 4 21600016430  272568  17.4
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
NEW_UPC         IRI_KEY     WEEK      DOLLARS
13000016961     272568      1220      3.29
13000016961     272568      1221      3.29
13000016961     272568      1222      3.29
13000016961     272568      1223      9.87
13000016962     272568      1224      3.29
13000016961     272568      1224      9.87
13000016962     272568      1225      3.29
13000016961     272568      1225      9.87
13000016962     272568      1226      3.29
13000016961     272568      1226      9.87
13000016961     272568      1227      9.87
13000016961     272568      1228      3.29
13000016963     272568      1228      3.29
13000016963     272568      1229      3.29
13000016962     272568      1230      3.29
13000016961     272568      1230      3.29
13000016963     272568      1230      13.16
13000016962     272568      1231      3.29
13000016963     272568      1231      9.87
21600016430     272568      1231      17.43
13000016962     272568      1232      9.87",
header = TRUE)
```